# Matplotlib plotting x ticks from Pandas DataFrame incorrectly

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame containing 20 rows, indexed by datetime:

```
df.tail()
                     units       value
time        
2013-08-30T13:01:12  vehicles/h  662
2013-08-30T13:06:12  vehicles/h  701
2013-08-30T13:11:13  vehicles/h  477
2013-08-30T13:16:13  vehicles/h  179
2013-08-30T13:21:13  vehicles/h  576
```

I'm plotting it using matplotlib, like so:

```
ax = ls.plot(color='CC00CC')
# Only show hours and minutes
ax.set_xticklabels(
    [dt.strftime("%H:%M:%S") for dt in ls.index.to_datetime()])
plt.setp(ax.get_yticklabels(), fontsize=8)
ax.set_ylabel("Counts")
ax.set_xlabel("5-minute intervals on %s" % (datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%d/%m/%Y")))
plt.title("Vehicles")
plt.tight_layout()
```

Which results in the following plot:

[image]

But only the first few times are being shown as x ticks. The right-most x tick should be labelled 12:21:13, and some more of the intermediate ticks should be shown. What have I done wrong?

Comment: you probably have to explicitly set the x-tick locations. Just formatting them might not be enough to override the auto-scale/auto-placement of the ticks.

Comment: `set_xlabel` de-couples your label text from you data.  It is dangerous and should only be used only occasionally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that I wasn't actually converting the `time` column to a DateTimeIndex properly. Doing that correctly fixed it:

Here's what my time column looked like:

```
df['time'][0]
>> u'2014-03-04T19:01:11'
```

Conversion like so:

```
# convert to DateTimeIndex, convert to UTC, and sort
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
df = df.set_index('time').tz_convert('UTC').sort()
```

Comment: Can you provide some more detail, please, for others in the same situation?

Comment: Yeah I'm stuck on this right now to. The question/answer is not helping.

Comment: @rcompton Added an example